# How to add loader on web page without having these tag (HTML,Head,body)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a loader on my child web page. i need when my all content is loaded then my loader remove and all content display

Answer (score 0):

you could add `position: relative` to the container with your content and add a `position: absolute` loader div with an animated gif which stretches over the complete container (add a `z-index` to make sure it stays on top).

Comment: Hey Dirk , i want to add  code on that page where html head and body tag is not exciting. 

<div id="loader" style=" display:block; position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 99999999; background: url('http://s18.postimg.org/adqxqu69x/712.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249,249,249); ">
</div>
<script>
var eventHandler = function (event)
{
 debugger;
 $("#loader").remove();
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',eventHandler);

</script>

this code is not working .